# signInSilently() generates an error code=-4

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I'm having this case where the GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently() is returning an error:

> Error Domain=com.google.GIDSignIn Code=-4 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (com.google.GIDSignIn error -4.)"

I can't seem to find any documentation of this error under the google signin docs or stackOverflow for that matter.

I'm expecting this to error to happen if I request a silent signIn for no previously signedIn user.
But to my surprise it even happens when I have a user previously signedIn and I attempt to signIn Silently a second time after a few seconds.

A second issue I'm having difficulty with is to determine if there is a user signed In using :

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser
```

which is either a nil or a GIDGoogleUser object.

Any help making progress on this issue would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Here are the error codes from `GIDSignIn.h`. The `-4` code is sent by `signInSilently` when there are no auth tokens in the keychain. See comments.

```
// A list of potential error codes returned from the Google Identity SDK.
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, GIDSignInErrorCode) {
  // Indicates an unknown error has occured.
  kGIDSignInErrorCodeUnknown = -1,
  // Indicates a problem reading or writing to the application keychain.
  kGIDSignInErrorCodeKeychain = -2,
  // Indicates no appropriate applications are installed on the user's device which can handle
  // sign-in. This code will only ever be returned if using webview and switching to browser have
  // both been disabled.
  kGIDSignInErrorCodeNoSignInHandlersInstalled = -3,
  // Indicates there are no auth tokens in the keychain. This error code will be returned by
  // signInSilently if the user has never signed in before with the given scopes, or if they have
  // since signed out.
  kGIDSignInErrorCodeHasNoAuthInKeychain = -4,
  // Indicates the user canceled the sign in request.
  kGIDSignInErrorCodeCanceled = -5,
};
```

For the Google SDKs in general I've found the header file comments are actually a pretty good place to look, usually more informative than any published documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet @jhabbott, any idea why the keychain item would not be found if the user signed in a few seconds ago ?

Comment: Nope - it should be ok if you used `signIn` the first time and it worked. Wish I knew any more!

Comment: Im having the exact same problem. I signIn and everything goes well. I can do silent signing again, and is okay. But if I kill the app and open it again, silent signIn fails with error -4. Like if its not saving anything in the Keychain any luck with this @jhabbott ?

Answer (score 9):

I've had the same problem. The problem was in method:

```
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] setScopes:@[@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read", @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"]];
```

you should call it before:

```
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] hasAuthInKeychain]
```

and

```
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn]
```

Comment: This was really driving me nuts... Actually I had to set the scope *twice*, yes *twice*. I printed the scope directly before the `signInSilently` call and it was just not working when there was only one entry in the array, but with twice the same scope in it, it did work... WTF Google?

Comment: Update: My solution from my previous comment only works on iOS 11 >.<

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue here, but I finally found the answer.
I found GoogleSignIn taking UserDefault for keeping previous sign-in status. Please check whether or not you use UserDefault to develop your application. If you do, please make sure you won't delete all of the data in your UserDefault if you want to keep previous sign-in status.

In my case,

```
public func resetUserDafault() {

   let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

   let dict = UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation()

   for key in dict.keys {

       //GoogleSignIn take this key to check previous signin status

       if key == "GID_AppHasRunBefore"{

           continue

       }

       userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: key);

  }

  UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    //After doing it, my application is working properly now.

    if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() == true{

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

    }
    else{

        //not sign in

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a custom button then you need to check auth in keychain.

```
if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() == true{

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

}
else{

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()

}
```

Comment: Not sure no one else has upvoted this, but this absolutely fixed it for me!!

Comment: This is the answer. In documentation somehow I didn't notice signIn() method.

Answer (score 2):

Igor Rotaru had the correct answer. The key is to have the scopes set before using `signInSilently`. It will check if the user has ever signed in before with the scopes that you previously set and signed in with.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer my answer from [Saving the current GIDGoogleUser instead of signing in on every launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517199/saving-the-current-gidgoogleuser-instead-of-signing-in-on-every-launch/34652951#34652951)

you should conform the GIDSignInUIDelegate protocol without implementing the methods.

```
signInWillDispatch:error: 
signIn:presentViewController:
signIn:dismissViewController:
```

It will fix your error -4.

Answer (score 0):

check if internet is available then proceed with your staff.
I got this error when iPad was not connected on the secondary signed in checks.

Answer (score 0):

Both Igor and Spydy worked for me

A swift version of Igor's post

```
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.hasAuthInKeychain()
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()

    // Uncomment to automatically sign in the user.
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
```

or from Spydy.

```
    // google sign in setup
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() == true{
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
    }
    else{
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }
```