# Saving the current GIDGoogleUser instead of signing in on every launch

Tags: ios, swift, google-oauth

I'm using the `GIDSignInButton` to sign my users into Google. Problem is, I'm not sure how to save the current user so that each user doesn't have to sign in every time they open the app. I've tried using `signInSilently()` but I get `The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GIDSignIn error -4.)` every time.

That error, in the header file, says this :

```
// Indicates there are no auth tokens in the keychain. This error code will be returned by
  // signInSilently if the user has never signed in before with the given scopes, or if they have
  // since signed out.
  kGIDSignInErrorCodeHasNoAuthInKeychain = -4,
```

In my case, the user has already signed in with the given scopes, and they have not signed out yet. So I'm not sure what could be causing that error.

After a user signs in, how should I save that instance where I'm able to use `signInSilently()` after that? Is there handling involved with the refresh and access tokens as well?

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Try to save complete object of GIDGoogleUser in user defaults using NSCoder/DECoder , and when app restart , BUt you have to check that token etc will not be unvalidate after a specific time.. hope this will help

Comment: I have the same issue, any luck @Ducky ?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you have not user signed out or even disconnected somewhere?

I'm always checking whether the user has either currently signed in or has previous authentication saved in using `hasAuthInKeychain` (e.g. in `viewWillAppear`):

```
private func checkIfGoogleUserIsAuthorized() {
    if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() {
        // User was previously authenticated to Google. Attempt to sign in.
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
    } else {
        // User was not previously authenticated to Google.
        self.updateUI()
    }
}
```

In case there is no authentication saved, you must trigger silent sign in and handle reply with your implementation of `GIDSignInDelegate` protocols `didSignInForUser` method.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I can do silentSignIn after normal SignIn and everything goes well. The problem is when I kill the app, doing a silentSignIn throws the -4 error. Is like is not saving anything in the KeyChain.  (by the way Im running in a iOS 9 device) apparently there are some issues with iOS 9 regarding KeyChain and GoogleSignIn (follow this thread: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/82). @dperk any luck ?

Comment: Same issue. So far the most problems of all the frameworks/libraries has been google.

Answer (score 0):

If, in your project, the class that implements `GIDSignInUIDelegate` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, then don't implement the

```
signInWillDispatch:error: 
signIn:presentViewController:
signIn:dismissViewController:
```

methods of the `GIDSignInUIDelegate` protocol.

Remove these methods from your view controller if you added.
but you should conform the `GIDSignInUIDelegate` protocol without implementing the methods.

It will fix your error -4.

Please refer [Google developers guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift#add_the_sign-in_button) for assistance