# How to retrieve age and gender from Google Sign-In

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I've integrated Google Sign-In into my iOS app.  I would like to access user's gender and age.  The documentation is not clear enough to see how to do this. I've figured out that I should request the right scope.  I haven't found an official list of scopes in the documentation, and I don't know which scope I should use.  Also I don't know how I should retrieve the data when I get it.  I would appreciate if someone help me to get this info from  Google.  Thanks!
Here's my code:

```
func googleLogin() {

    self.appDelegate.setIdentityAvailableValue(false)

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = kClientId
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().shouldFetchBasicProfile = true
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {

    if (error == nil) {

        let idToken = user.authentication.idToken

        let url = NSURL(string:  "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=\(user.authentication.accessToken)")
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            //UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            if error != nil {
                print("dataTaskWithURL error \(error)")
            }
            else {
                do {
                    let userData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as? [String:AnyObject]
                    /*
                    Get the account information you want here from the dictionary
                    Possible values are
                    "id": "...",
                    "email": "...",
                    "verified_email": ...,
                    "name": "...",
                    "given_name": "...",
                    "family_name": "...",
                    "link": "https://plus.google.com/...",
                    "picture": "https://lh5.googleuserco...",
                    "gender": "...",
                    "locale": "..."

                    so in my case:
                    */
                    let gender = userData!["gender"] as! String
                    let locale = userData!["locale"] as! String
                    print("gender = \(gender)")
                    print("locale = \(locale)")

                } catch {
                    NSLog("Account Information could not be loaded")
                }
            }
        })

    } else {
        // some error handling code
    }
}
```

Comment: @user-You can not find age from google sigh -in.because google sign in has stopped to give age of any user .

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the age.

Comment: If it useful for you then vote for my comment friend.

Comment: @ DEVENDRA AGNIHOTRI I finally was able to get the info I needed.  The age in the form of age range is part of the info that I got.  So it's not absolutely true that Google doesn't give age info.

Comment: How you getting age?

Comment: List of scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes

Answer (score 5):

This is **Swift 3** :

Simply use following  method :

```
 func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
                  withError error: Error!)
```

**User info retrieving Code :**  and put this code inside above method -

```
let gplusapi = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=\(user.authentication.accessToken!)"
            let url = NSURL(string: gplusapi)!


            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            let session = URLSession.shared


            session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                do {
                    let userData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:[]) as? [String:AnyObject]
                    let picture = userData!["picture"] as! String
                    let gender = userData!["gender"] as! String
                    let locale = userData!["locale"] as! String

                } catch {
                    NSLog("Account Information could not be loaded")
                }

            }).resume()
```

You need to call resume() at the end or else the closure will not get called.It took me three days to figure this out. So I hope this will help somebody.

Comment: still I m not getting gender in response, picture is there

Comment: Thanks a lot. Save my time. :)

Comment: im able to get gender but what scope should be used for getting user birthdate?

Comment: userData is giving this response where is gender?                       ["picture": https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg, "family_name": User, "name": User, "email": torqdevuser2@gmail.com, "sub": 10855413580866685, "given_name": dev, "locale": en, "email_verified": 1]

Answer (score 1):

> You can only access what a user has set to public. If the user doesn't want this information public then you cant have the information.

```
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
        if (error == nil) {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
            let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
            let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
            let name = user.profile.name
            let email = user.profile.email

          let url = NSURL(string:  "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=\(user.authentication.accessToken)")
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        do {
            let userData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as? [String:AnyObject]
            /*
            Get the account information you want here from the dictionary
            Possible values are
            "id": "...",
            "email": "...",
            "verified_email": ...,
            "name": "...",
            "given_name": "...",
            "family_name": "...",
            "link": "https://plus.google.com/...",
            "picture": "https://lh5.googleuserco...",
            "gender": "...",
            "locale": "..."

            so in my case:
            */
           let gender = userData!["gender"] as! String
           let locale = userData!["locale"] as! String

        } catch {
            NSLog("Account Information could not be loaded")
        }
    }

        } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user:GIDGoogleUser!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
        // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
        // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  This code doesn't work.  The closure never gets called.  I also changed it to have the form of session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in, but still it never gets called!  
I do get the following error: 
Error Domain=com.google.GIDSignIn Code=-4 "(null)"
2016-03-04 21:19:22.292 One[8794:5006509] url.scheme:  com.googleusercontent.apps./*my url scheme*/

Comment: the code 100 % work , but you forget to add some lines in this code see this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461139/signinsilently-generates-an-error-code-4

Comment: I added your code to the successful signin part of signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!).  That means the login worked successfully.  What code am I missing?