# How to fetch Google logged in user birthday and gender objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gidsignin

How can we get google logged in user age and genger in objective c. I make that user's profile information public.
code:

```
NSString *userId = user.userID;                  // For client-side use only!
NSString *idToken = user.authentication.idToken; // Safe to send to the server
NSString *fullName = user.profile.name;
NSString *givenName = user.profile.givenName;
NSString *familyName = user.profile.familyName;
NSString *email = user.profile.email;
```

I checked below links but not find any solution.

https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get

[Retrieving date of birth and marital status with Google OAuth API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612357/retrieving-date-of-birth-and-marital-status-with-google-oauth-api)

Comment: see this for e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35809947/how-to-retrieve-age-and-gender-from-google-sign-in

Comment: Thanks for the reply but still not able to see gender and birthday in response.