# After logging with FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail , GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() is null

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

On my Swift app I have managed to login using the Google button as stated clearly [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start?ver=swift)

I also want to login users in Firebase using the email/password method, following [these](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth) steps

The problem is that after the user logs in the following is always false

```
if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain(){
```

How can the Firebase login "update" the hasAuthInKeychain in order to check if the user has logged in?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here, but I finally found the answer.

Please take a look in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43338910/7848589).

```
public func resetUserDafault() {

   let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

   let dict = UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation()

   for key in dict.keys {

       //GoogleSignIn take this key to check previous signin status

       if key == "GID_AppHasRunBefore"{

           continue

       }

       userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: key);

  }

  UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    //After doing it, my application is working properly now.

    if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() == true{

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

    }
    else{

        //not sign in

    }

}
```